# Is MapView caching the titles by default?

Tags: android, google-maps, caching, android-mapview

I have an application, which make use of google maps as a MapView component. The app is also using a DB containing of a single table with 4 columns (number and varchar(255), no BLOBs or alike) and some `SharedPreferences`.

If I check  the `apps` section in systems settings, I can see, that the size of the app is around 10 MB, 400 kB of data and whole 40 MB of cache. I assume, that the later is taken by map's tiles.

Am I right? Are the map contents are cached to save traffic?

Comment: yes tiles are cached from google maps, you cannot prevent it or access those tiles though

Comment: yeah, that's fine. I want the users to save traffic through default caching, nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tiles for "Google Maps" are automatically cached. Please be aware that if you add your own overlay, caching is a bit less good, and you should manage some way to save your cache (I usually use LRUCache in persistent files, so I can also perform manual "sync" cache tasks for my custom tiles).

If you want to delete the cache, you can access the ExternalCacheDir or CacheDir for your application and cleanup.
If you need further help, just comment here!